# Ошибка получения веб элемента по классу selenium, в яндекс поисковике

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, яндекс-поиск

Пытаюсь запарсить картинки в яндекс поисковике. После исследования элемента в FireFox нашёл класс к которому принадлежит тег с картинкой. Пытаюсь получить этот эелемент с помощью кодом ниже

```
firs_elemen = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('serp-item_pos_0')
```

Но высвечивается ошибка

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: serp-item_pos_0
```

Здесь кусок элемента со всеми классами

```
<div class="serp-item serp-item_type_search serp-item_group_search serp-item_pos_0 serp-item_scale_yes serp-item_commercial-snippet-size_one-line serp-item_commercial-snippet-action_link justifier__item i-bem serp-item_loaded serp-item_js_inited" ...
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Потому что класс serp-item_pos_0 строится с помощью js а вы парсите html страницу до запуска скриптов

Answer (score 0):

Просто css локатор неправильный. Надо так:

```
firs_elemen = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.serp-item_pos_0')
```